# Is there a way to extract Last run (date) , last expired from Airflow for a DAG and sent over an email

Tags: airflow

I am looking to automate the manual process of checking DAG's status (success/failure) from Last Run , Last Expired Date of a DAG .

Currently our DAG's are scheduled to run at time

```
Current hour - 2hrs .
```

Issue : At times scheduler stops and the jobs start to fail . To avoid this I need to set up and email which will give info about DAG success and its Last Run , last Expired fields .

I checked these fields are available in mysql (database for airflow); under 
Database : airflow
Table : dag .

Is there a way I can extract these fields through Airflow UI or through mysql and sent it throug email?

Comment: your goal is to send an email on failure of a job right?  Why not use the `email_on_failure=True` parameter in the DAG?

Comment: If you are battling against `scheduler` going down, then of course, your **monitoring / alerting solution has to be independent of `Airflow`** (otherwise who will run your `Airflow` alerting task if the `scheduler` itself went down?). In this regard, you can look at `statsd` ([`scheduler_heartbeat`](https://airflow.apache.org/metrics.html#counters)) or `airflow-prometheus-exporter` ([`canary_dag`](https://github.com/robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter#requirements))

Comment: As for getting **last-execution-date** of a DAG, you can use [`last_dag_run`](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#list_dag_runs) command of `Airflow CLI`